# Conjugacy class definition in terms of sets

Tags: group-theory

In a given solution to one of the problems in my book, the author writes the following:

> Every conjugacy class of a group $G$ may be written $$G_i = \{gg_ig^{-1} \mid g_i \in G\}.$$

To my eyes, this is surely a mistake. In fact, the statement should be as follows no?

> Every conjugacy class of a group $G$ may be written $$G_i = \{gg_ig^{-1} \mid g \in G\}.$$

That is, a conjugacy class can be constructed by fixing an element (here, $g_i$) and considering the action of all inner automorphisms on $G$. Perhaps I am missing something though and the two are actually equivalent?

Comment: Your definition is correct I think, but whcih book are you following

Here have a look,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class#Definition

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! It is Szekeres's *A Course in Mathematical Physics* (but the solution manual). @DeeponjitBose

Comment: The first class is all of $G$.  Given $h\in G$ arbitrary, then taking $g_i=g^{-1}hg$ shows that $h$ is in the first collection (poorly named $G_i$ though it does not depend on $i$).

Answer (score 1):

IMO it is precise to say equivalence class of $g$, where $g\in G$. Conjugacy relation on $G$ is defined by, $g\sim h$ if and only if $\exists k\in G$ such that $g=k^{-1}hk$. It’s easy to check conjugacy is an equivalence relation. So $$\begin{align}[g]&= \{h\in G\mid h\sim g\}\\ &=\{h\in G\mid h=k^{-1}gk\text{ for some $k\in G$}\} \\ &=\{k^{-1}gk\mid k\in G\}.\end{align}$$